How to attach a class method as an ESP32 hardware timer ISR callback
I have a follow up question to this one: How to attach a class function as an ISR callback
I want to use an ESP32 hardware timer to periodically trigger calls to a class method.  I created the hardware timer (PumpPulseTimer) and I now need to attach the PumpTimer_ISR() method from the PumpControl class as the callback.  When I try this: timerAttachInterrupt( PumpPulseTimer, &PumpTimer_ISR, true ); the compiler fails with this error:
error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&PumpControl::PumpTimer_ISR' [-fpermissive]
   timerAttachInterrupt( PumpPulseTimer, &PumpTimer_ISR, true );
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
.pio/libdeps/featheresp32/Pump/Pump Functions.cpp:99:62: error: cannot convert 'void (PumpControl::*)()' to 'void (*)()'
   timerAttachInterrupt( PumpPulseTimer, &PumpTimer_ISR, true );
                                                              ^

when I try this: timerAttachInterrupt( PumpPulseTimer, std::bind(&PumpControl::PumpTimer_ISR, this), true ); it yield this error:
error: cannot convert 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (PumpControl::*)(), PumpControl*>::type' {aka 'std::_Bind<void (PumpControl::*(PumpControl*))()>'} to 'void (*)()'
   timerAttachInterrupt( PumpPulseTimer, std::bind(&PumpControl::PumpTimer_ISR, this), true );
                                         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Any ideas on how to fix this?

&PumpControl::PumpTimer_ISR is a member function pointer while void (*)() is a pointer to a free function. The former cannot be passed as argument for the latter.

Use timerAttachInterruptArg(hw_timer_t *timer, void (*userFunc)(void *), void *arg) to forward execution into a new static void IRAM_ATTR PumpControl::timer_isr(void* arg) function, where you give arg as this (PumpControl*), from that you can cast arg back to the correct type and call into the member function again.

I diagree with closing this question, since it has a unique solution within the Arduino-ESP32 framework, which is a much better solution that in the question marked as its duplicate.
https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/3.0.4/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-timer.h#L50-L52

@MaximilianGerhardt Casting a member function pointer to void* will be ill-formed(or undefined behavior atleast).

But that's not done, @user12002570 . timerAttachInterruptArg(PumpPulseTimer, &PumpControl::timer_isr, (void*)this); with static void PumpControl::timer_isr(void* arg) { PumpControl* pObj = (PumpControl*) arg; pObj->PumpTimer_ISR(); }

@MaximilianGerhardt - my compiler says  identifier "timerAttachInterruptArg" is undefinedC/C++(20)

My bad, that's only in the Arduino-ESP32 3.x core, while PlatformIO is still on 2.x (for political reasons..). You could use a forked platform that gives 3.x (https://github.com/pioarduino/platform-espressif32), or use the generic techinque in the referenced duplicate question.
